# Why am I getting "Installation failed due to invalid APK file!" when I run my app?

Tags: android

Does anyone know what to do about this error? I am getting this every time I try to run my application on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

> Installation failed due to invalid APK file!

I am using the stock JB ROM. I've tried everything, and just can't get it to work.

Comment: did you accepting the "unknown resources" checkbox in the applications menu in settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved this problem by updating my s3 to from 4.1.1 to 4.1.2, worked fine straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Simple your apk file is invalid. Try to download a fresh file. Some times it happens when the file become corrupt. It may be due to many problems like latency of network when you are downloading the apk or lack of packet receiving due to problems in network. Try to download a fresh file again that will work. If that again doesn't work then the apk file available on server in not right.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the apk on your simulator?It seems the apk file self case the problem.

Comment: The APK is pushed to my device using eclipse "Run" I am debugging it. Yes, the APK is developed by me. It works on a simulator, just not on my real device.

Answer (score 0):

If its (apk) prepared by you. Then you might have forgot signing the apk with your own keystore. Please refer Android developers guide for generating the keystore and signing the application.